# Can I add google calendar to outlook without synching/downloading gmail eMails?

Tags: macos, windows-10, microsoft-outlook, gmail

I want to read my gmail calendar in Outlook 2016 (Mac and or Windows). Editing would be a plus.
I use Outlook for work eMail only and don't want it to download my gmail address, but I do want to see my personal gmail calendar to avoid date collisions when adding work events.

Alternatively, can I add my Microsoft Exchange account to the Google Web Calendar?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure whether you want to achieve this via macros, but without using macros, you can try subscribing to your Google calendar in Outlook. See:

[See your Google Calendar in Outlook](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/see-your-google-calendar-in-outlook-c1dab514-0ad4-4811-824a-7d02c5e77126)

Update:

1. Log in to your Google Calendar account.
2. In the left column, click My calendars to expand it, click the arrow button next to the calendar that you want to add to Outlook as an Internet Calendar Subscription, and then select **Settings and sharing**.

[image]

3. In the opened page, scroll down to the "Integrate calendar" heading. Find the "Public address in iCal format" line.
4. Copy the URL which is the .ics URL you need to enter in Outlook.
5. Next steps in Outlook should be the same as it mentioned in the article I mentioned above.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your reply.
Unfortunately this description is, like I said, completly outdated. Neither Google Calendar nore Outlook 2016 have this GUI anymore. Never the less, rereading these instructions, I realized, that in Google Calendar, one has to create first a new calendar and then go to its settings. There I found the ical address. Unfortunately, I was not able to use this address in Outlook 2016, as the option 'add web calendar' is gone.

Comment: Oops! Didn't realize that. However, this is still possible, just some change in the Google Calendar GUI. Since images cannot be inserted in comment, I'll edit my answer to include more details.

Comment: @Steve Fan:  Yes, but the last line isn't cool... Who wants a public calendar??  Not a good idea at all.  Want to give the bad guys a map to your house so when you go on vacation they are all set?  Or, is there a way to also keep the calendar private and add it to Outlook?

Comment: @DaaBoss: Thanks for your heads up. Yes, there is indeed also a private ical address, called "secret address in ical format" under the same settings for the current version of google calendar.
It's too bad that both companies change their GUI layout so often that even their own documentation is outdated. The only successful combination of both calendars (Google and Exchange) for me has been Apple iCal under macOS. Everything else failed ...

Answer (score 0):

If adding the Google calendar link in the Outlook app, as described in the previous answer, does not work, try adding that same link in a browser using Outlook online at this link: https://outlook.office.com/calendar/addcalendar

In other words go to Outlook, go to the calendar, click on Add Calendar, click on Subscribe from Web, and paste the link there.

[image]